# How to make keyboard Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I want to make a keyboard activity i-e whenever my activity starts it shows a computer type QWERTY keyboard on fullscreen.Actually I am making an application through which user will be able to use android keyboard for the Computer vi WiFi.

Comment: Can't you just set up the Activity in landscape from the Manifest and have a single EditText with Focus so the keyboard pops up ?

Comment: but I dont need editText or something like that.I will pass its input to computer through socket programming.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using and `EditText` with a `TextWatcher`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html